# How does custom object detection actually work?

Tags: tensorflow, tensorflow2.0

I am currently testing out custom object detection using the Tensorflow API. But I don't quite seem to understand the theory behind it.
So if I for example download a version of MobileNet and use it to train on, lets say, red and green apples. Does it forget all the things that is has already been trained on? And if so, why does it then benefit to use MobileNet over building a CNN from scratch.

Thanks for any answers!

Comment: Do you mean you are using the imageClassifier with mobilenet model? In that case, you can improve upon the imageClassifier by retraining the Neural Network part with new features of your own images. The classes from mobilenet will also still be recognised.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Does it forget all the things that is has already been trained on?

Yes, if you re-train a CNN previously trained on a large database with a new database containing fewer classes it will "forget" the old classes. However, the old pre-training can help learning the new classes, this is a training strategy called "transfert learning" of "fine tuning" depending on the exact approach.

As a rule of thumb it is generally not a good idea to create a new network architecture from scratch as better networks probably already exist. You may want to implement your custom architecture if:

- You are learning CNN's and deep learning
- You have a specific need and you proved that other architectures won't fit or will perform poorly

Usually, one take an existing pre-trained network and specialize it for their specific task using transfert learning.

A lot of scientific literature is available for free online if you want to learn. you can start with the Yolo series and R-CNN, Fast-RCNN and Faster-RCNN for detection networks.

Answer (score 0):

The main concept behind object detection is that it divides the input image in a grid of N patches, and then for each patch, it generates a set of sub-patches with different aspect ratios, let's say it generates M rectangular sub-patches. In total you need to classify MxN images.

In general the idea is then analyze each sub-patch within each patch . You pass the sub-patch to the classifier in your model and depending on the model training, it will classify it as containing a green apple/red apple/nothing. If it is classified as a red apple, then this sub-patch is the bounding box of the object detected.

So actually, there are two parts you are interested in:

1. Generating as many sub-patches as possible to cover as many portions of the image as possible (Of course, the more sub-patches, the slower your model will be) and,
2. The classifier. The classifier is normally an already exisiting network (MobileNeet, VGG, ResNet...). This part is commonly used as the "backbone" and it will extract the features of the input image. With the classifier you can either choose to training it "from zero", therefore your weights will be adjusted to your specific problem, OR, you can load the weigths from other known problem and use them in your problem so you won't need to spend time training them. In this case, they will also classify the objects for which the classifier was training for.

Take a look at [the Mask-RCNN implementation](https://github.com/matterport/Mask_RCNN). I find very interesting how they explain the process. In this architecture, you will not only generate a bounding box but also segment the object of interest.